# Cannot convert from float to int

Tags: java, compilation, processing

I have some code like this:

```
void drawPlot()
{
    String[] dataItemPrices = loadStrings("itemPrices.csv");  //load in .csv file, store as string array
    itemName = new String[dataItemPrices.length-1];
    itemPrice = new float[dataItemPrices.length-1];

    for (int i=0; i<dataItemPrices.length-1; i++) 
    {
        //split array to consider commas
        String[] tokensItemPrices = dataItemPrices[i+1].split(",");   
        itemName[i] = tokensItemPrices[0];
        itemPrice[i] = Float.parseFloat(tokensItemPrices[1]);

        dataMin = min(dataMin,itemPrice[i]); 
        dataMax = max(dataMax,itemPrice[i]); 

        itemPriceScaled = new float[map(itemPrice[i], dataMin, dataMax, 
                                        0, (height-100))];
    }
}
```

The last line of code is causing problems, when I compile I get "cannot convert from float to int".

The only int is the [i] but that's used to access an array, it can't be that can it? Otherwise how can I access the array?

Help please!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `map` method?

Comment: Could you post the actual error line as you see while compiling?

Comment: Could you post the complete `drawPlot()` method?  What you've shown is missing imporant declarations, such as the declarations of `itemPriceScaled`, and `map()`.

Comment: drawPlot is all there i hope. Absurdity you should post the code for map too and all the declarations for the variables used inside these methods... When in doubt just post the whole class code.

Comment: The map method is here:

https://processing.org/reference/map_.html

map(value, start1, stop1, start2, stop2). Parameters 
value float: the incoming value to be converted
start1 float: lower bound of the value's current range
stop1 float: upper bound of the value's current range
start2 float: lower bound of the value's target range
stop2 float: upper bound of the value's target range
Returns float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible alternatives:

1. You are creating a new float array and you need an int size for it, does `map` return a float? If this is the case, `map` could need major modifications.
2. What kind of parameters does `map` need?  itemPrice[i], dataMin and dataMax are all floats(height could be too), is this correct? In this case, a cast to (int) could be enough or your function prototype needs to be fixed...

Please add the code for `map` and all variables declarations to your question.

*Edit:*

After your comment and looking at your code, maybe this is what you want to do: populating an array with prices (taken from the itemPrice array) "scaled" using `map` that has obviously the same size as the other two arrays:

```
void drawPlot()
{
    String[] dataItemPrices = loadStrings("itemPrices.csv");  //load in .csv file, store as string array
    itemName = new String[dataItemPrices.length-1];
    itemPrice = new float[dataItemPrices.length-1];
    itemPriceScaled = new float[dataItemPrices.length-1]; // <<<<<Added

    for (int i=0; i<dataItemPrices.length-1; i++) 
    {
        //split array to consider commas
        String[] tokensItemPrices = dataItemPrices[i+1].split(",");   
        itemName[i] = tokensItemPrices[0];
        itemPrice[i] = Float.parseFloat(tokensItemPrices[1]);

        dataMin = min(dataMin,itemPrice[i]); 
        dataMax = max(dataMax,itemPrice[i]); 

        itemPriceScaled[i] = map(itemPrice[i], dataMin, dataMax, 
                                        0, (height-100)); //<<<Modified
    }
}
```

Comment: The map method is here:

https://processing.org/reference/map_.html

map(value, start1, stop1, start2, stop2). Parameters 
value float: the incoming value to be converted
start1 float: lower bound of the value's current range
stop1 float: upper bound of the value's current range
start2 float: lower bound of the value's target range
stop2 float: upper bound of the value's target range
Returns float

Comment: It returns a float, you can't use that to give the size to an array (e.g. an array with 1.5 elements??), are you sure that's what you want to do? I'm editing my answer.

Comment: user43250937 I'm so sorry for wording my question badly. I see what you've done, it's really smart and the error is gone. However, for some reason the map function didn't do what I expected. I'm trying to figure this out, itemPrice[0] is 11.29, so scaled in the range 0 to 600 (height is 700 here and original range is 0.6 to 58.4), itemPriceScaled[0] should be around 117. Instead I get NaN. For itemPrice[1]=39.63, itemPriceScaled[1] is 600. I'm confused again =/ I suck..

Comment: Something is wrong with those parameters, try printing them out and check if the values are what you expect. Other than this it seems you are using map correctly, it should be: map(valueToConvert, OriginalFromRange, OriginalToRange, ScaledFromRange,ScaledToRange), and you have done it this way.

Comment: Ok, I ll mess around with it. I would up vote and stuff but I'm too noob on here so I can't do it =/